# This financial statements or these financial statements

Tags: word-usage

When referring to a financial statements document of a company, should it be treated as a singular or plural noun phrase?

Should I say, 'This financial statements includes...' or 'These financial statements include...'?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Plural.

- These - demonstrative determiner
- Financial - adjective
- Statements - noun

The noun is "statements" and is plural.  Financial is simply an adjective describing the noun.  Therefore the article should be plural, "these".

[Determiners](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/nouns/what/what-is-a-determiner.html)

- Articles (a, the) express specificity of a noun
- Demonstratives (this, these) require a reference to refer to the object
- Quantifiers (all, few) point out how much or how little is being indicated
- Possessives (their, my) indicates belonging

Comment: A small point: the definite article is "the". "These" is a plural demonstrative determinative, here functioning as a determiner. The demonstratives are "this, these, that, those"

Comment: I agree with @BillJ, and the determiner should agree in number with the noun it determines. I'll upvote your answer as soon as you edit it.

Comment: Yep, good point.

Answer (score 0):

**Financial statements** is a term that usually refers not merely to a number of statements, but rather to a number of different kinds of statements. To treat the term as having a singular referent shows ignorance not only of English grammar but also of financial practice.